# jmeter listeners not giving any results, if we import ".jmx" file from blazemeter and execute. i am using Ubuntu as my system OS

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

i used blazemeter for recording the steps which i followed in my website. then i saved those steps using the extension  ".jmx" . After that opened jmeter and open the file which we saved (the file with extension ".jmx")before from blazemeter. All requests displayed in the test plan node. i just added listeners to the test plan node, set all required threads. Then i run the test requests.

**result which i got is :** 
2017/08/19 15:53:26 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.HTMLParseError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser

Note: i am using Ubuntu in my system, added blazemeter in chrome browser.

Hope you people could help me to solve my issue. Expecting the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [JMeter package details in Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) the latest version which is available from the repositories is JMeter 2.13 which is 2+ years old therefore script, generated by the BlazeMeter recorded might not work on your old JMeter version.

According to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) users are encouraged to [always use the latest version of JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version), so:

1. Install Java 8 (or newer)
2. Get the latest version of JMeter from [JMeter downloads page](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) (current version is [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32))
3. Make sure you are running the **downloaded** version of JMeter, not the one you installed from Ubuntu repositories, i.e. use:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin
   ./jmeter
   ```

   instead of `jmeter`